# Collect all Similar Persons to One Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a person with several Id's.
Some of them in Column Id1 and Some of them in Id2.
I want to collect all the same persons Id's to one group.

If id1=10, is in the same row with id2=20. so it's mean that person with id1=10 he is the same person like id2=20.

The Input and Output example:

#### Input

```
Id1     Id2
---     ---
10      20
10      30
30      30
10      40

50      70
60      50
70      70
```

#### Output

```
NewId   OldId
-----   -----
1       10
1       20
1       30
1       40

2       50
2       60
2       70
```

Comment: expected result plz

Comment: Do you want select statement which have two columns are same or insert  id3 at the time id1 and id2 are same..?

Comment: What do you mean by union? Please add a sample to the question that contains the information you'd expect from the data in your screenshot.

Comment: Your question is far from comprehensible. Please re-edit. Also, solutions may differ across different DBMSs. Specify which one you are using.

Comment: It seems to me that English is not your native language. And you have a Slavic name. Perhaps it will be easier for you to ask on [ru.stackoverflow.com](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: Based on what criteria will `NewId` be chosen? Where does it come from? Why is it the same for the first three records in your example?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar NewId will be the same for all the id's in ID1 and ID2 that are equal.

Comment: Not in your example. What you say is not consistent with your examples. As all the IDs in your first screenshot are equal in ID1 and ID2, either `NewId` should be `1` for all the rows or distinct for of them. I ask again: Why is it `1` for the first three rows, but not for the following rows?

Comment: @FDavidov Done,Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this could be done with recursive CTEs, but here is a less elegent solution.

```
-- CREATE Temps
CREATE TABLE #Table (id1 INT, id2 INT)
CREATE TABLE #NewTable (NewID INT, OldID INT)
CREATE TABLE #AllIDs (ID INT)

-- Insert Test data
INSERT #Table
        ( id1, id2 )
VALUES  (  10, 20 ),
        (  10, 30 ),
        (  30, 20 ),
        (  10, 40 ),

        (  50, 70 ),
        (  60, 50 ),
        (  70, 70 ),
        (  110, 120 ),
        (  120, 130 ),
        (  140, 130 )

-- Assemble all possible OldIDs
INSERT INTO #AllIDs
    SELECT id1 FROM #Table
    UNION
    SELECT id2 FROM #Table

DECLARE @NewID INT = 1,
        @RowCnt int

-- Insert seed OldID
INSERT #NewTable
    SELECT TOP 1 @NewID, id
    FROM #AllIDs
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT OldID FROM #NewTable)
    ORDER BY 2

SET @RowCnt = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE @RowCnt > 0
BEGIN   
    WHILE @RowCnt > 0
    BEGIN
        -- Check for id2 that match current OldID
        INSERT #NewTable
            SELECT DISTINCT @NewID, id2
            FROM #Table t
                INNER JOIN #NewTable nt ON t.id1 = nt.OldID
            WHERE nt.[NewID] = @NewID
                AND t.id2 NOT IN (SELECT OldID FROM #NewTable WHERE [NewID] = @NewID)

        SELECT @RowCnt = @@ROWCOUNT

        -- Check for id1 that match current OldID
        INSERT #NewTable
            SELECT DISTINCT @NewID, id1
            FROM #Table t
                INNER JOIN #NewTable nt ON t.id2 = nt.OldID
            WHERE nt.[NewID] = @NewID
                AND t.id1 NOT IN (SELECT OldID FROM #NewTable WHERE [NewID] = @NewID)

        SELECT @RowCnt = @RowCnt + @@ROWCOUNT
    END

    SET @NewID = @NewID + 1

    -- Add another seed OldID if any left
    INSERT #NewTable
        SELECT TOP 1 @NewID, id
        FROM #AllIDs
        WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT OldID FROM #NewTable)
        ORDER BY 2

    SELECT @RowCnt = @@ROWCOUNT
END

-- Get Results
SELECT * FROM #NewTable ORDER BY [NewID], OldID
```

Comment: It can be done with recursive query. This question was asked on dba.se as well and I wrote detailed [answer there](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156606/57105).

Answer (score 2):

For recursive tasks you should use recursive CTE.

```
with cq as 
    (
        select distinct Id2, Id1 from #Tmp -- get your table 
        union
        select distinct Id1, Id2 from #Tmp -- get your table (or sort output)
        union
        select distinct Id1, Id1 from #Tmp -- add root from Id1 
        union
        select distinct Id2, Id2 from #Tmp -- add root from Id2
    ), cte (Id1, Id2, lvl) 
    as (
        select t.Id1, t.Id2, 0 lvl 
        from cq t
        union all
        select t2.Id2, c.Id1, lvl + 1 lvl 
        from cq t2, cte c
        where t2.Id1 = c.Id2
            and t2.Id1 != c.Id1 
            and c.lvl < 5 -- maximum level of recursion
        )
    select 
        Id1, 
        min(Id2) FirstId1,
        dense_rank() over(order by min(Id2)) rn
    from cte
    group by Id1
```

Max lvl and condition with != isn't necessary if your table will be well ordered.

Comment: This doesn't work with EarlOfEnnui's additional case proposed below: values (10, 20),(10, 30),(30, 30),(10, 40),(40, 45),(20, 40),(50, 70),(60, 50),(70, 70),(80, 80),(80, 120),(90, 120)

Comment: @SMM, if you are interested, it can be done with recursive query. This question was asked on dba.se as well and I wrote detailed [answer there](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156606/57105).

Comment: Fixed (for values Id2 > Id1).

Comment: You may control hierarchy path so you needn't  fixed level `and c.lvl < 5 -- maximum level of recursion`

Answer (score 1):

Anna, is that a good example?
This is a connected components issue.

#### Input

```
Id1     Id2
---     ---
10      20
10      30
30      30
10      40

50      70
60      50
70      70
```

#### Output

```
NewId   OldId
-----   -----
1       10
1       20
1       30
1       40

2       50
2       60
2       70
```

Comment: Yes, This is Exactly what i want!

Answer (score 1):

The CTE version. Note that I have added a few more data points to simulate duplicates and lone Ids.

```
--create test data
declare @table table (Id1 int, Id2 int);
insert  @table values 
        (10, 20),
        (10, 30),
        (30, 30),
        (10, 40),
        (40, 45),
        (20, 40),
        (50, 70),
        (60, 50),
        (70, 70),
        (80, 80);
select  *
from    @table;

--join related IDs with recursive CTE
;with min_first_cte as (
        select  case when Id1 <= Id2 then Id1 else Id2 end Id1,
                case when Id1 <= Id2 then Id2 else Id1 end Id2
        from    @table
), related_ids_cte as (
        --anchor IDs
        select  distinct Id1 BaseId, Id1 ParentId, Id1 ChildId
        from    min_first_cte
        where   Id1 not in (    select  Id2
                                from    min_first_cte
                                where   Id2 <> Id1)
        union all
        --related recursive IDs
        select  r.BaseId, m.Id1 ParentId, M.Id2 ChildId
        from    min_first_cte   m
        join    related_ids_cte r
                on  r.ChildId = m.Id1
                and m.Id1 <> m.Id2
), distinct_ids_cte as (
        select  distinct r.BaseId, r.ChildId
        from    related_ids_cte r
)
select  dense_rank() over (order by d.BaseId) [NewId],
        d.ChildId OldId
from    distinct_ids_cte d
order   by BaseId, ChildId;
```

Comment: This might have a flaw. Try these 
"insert @table values (10, 20),(10, 30),(30, 30),(10, 40),(40, 45),(20, 40),(50, 70),(60, 50),(70, 70),(80, 80),(80, 120),(90, 120);"

Comment: @EarlOfEnnui You're right. Recursion is really good where you can clearly identify the base members. I'll have to revisit this when I have some more time.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, it's about finding connected components given a list of connected pairs. And then, assign each of the groups a new id. The following implementation works:

```
CREATE TABLE #pairs (a int, b int)
CREATE TABLE #groups (a int, group_id int)

INSERT INTO #pairs
VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (5, 7), (3, 9), (8, 10), (11, 12), (1, 3)

-- starting stage - all items belong to their own group
INSERT INTO #groups(a, group_id)
SELECT a, a
  FROM #pairs
 UNION
SELECT b, b
  FROM #pairs

DECLARE @a INT
DECLARE @b INT
DECLARE @cGroup INT

SET ROWCOUNT 0
SELECT * INTO #mytemp FROM #pairs

SET ROWCOUNT 1

SELECT @a = a, @b = b FROM #mytemp

WHILE @@rowcount <> 0
BEGIN
    SET ROWCOUNT 0

    DECLARE @aGroup INT, @bGroup INT, @newGroup INT
    SELECT @aGroup = group_id FROM #groups WHERE a = @a
    SELECT @bGroup = group_id FROM #groups WHERE a = @b
    SELECT @newGroup = MIN(group_id) FROM #groups WHERE a IN (@a, @b)

    -- update the grouping table with the new group
    UPDATE #groups 
       SET group_id = @newGroup 
     WHERE group_id IN (@aGroup, @bGroup)

    DELETE FROM #mytemp 
     WHERE a = @a 
       AND b = @b

    SET ROWCOUNT 1
    SELECT @a = a, @b = b FROM #mytemp
END
SET ROWCOUNT 0

SELECT * FROM #groups

DROP TABLE #mytemp
DROP TABLE #pairs
DROP TABLE #groups
```

Here's the explanation:

- initially, assign each number a group of it's own value
- iterate over the pairs
- for each pair

  - find the minimum as set it as the new group id
  - set the group id to all the numbers where the current group id is the same as for the numbers in the current pair

In terms of a procedure, these are 2 iterations continuously updating the group ids to the minimum in the group - O(n2).